# 5pt font for Neopixel shield

Tags: led, adafruit, neopixel

I have a 5x8 Neopixel shield for my Arduino. I want to display text on it, while it is in "landscape mode", i.e. a only 5pt high text. The default font that is used by the `print`command is 8pt high. How can I load a font with 5pt height into my code?

I understand that the Neopixel library depends on `Adafruit GFX`, which allows for different fonts. But changing the font according to the Adafruit tutorial on GFX to one of the supplied fonts does not return any readable text (only a moving line of dots). I found this [font converter](http://oleddisplay.squix.ch/#/home) and used it to produce a 5pt font, but again only a moving dot appears.

This is my code (basically the Neomatrix example with modified orientation of the matrix):

```
// Adafruit_NeoMatrix example for single NeoPixel Shield.
// Scrolls 'Howdy' across the matrix in a portrait (vertical) orientation.

#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoMatrix.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <Fonts/Dialog_plain_5.h>
#ifndef PSTR
 #define PSTR // Make Arduino Due happy
#endif

#define PIN 6

Adafruit_NeoMatrix matrix = Adafruit_NeoMatrix(8, 5, PIN,
  NEO_MATRIX_TOP     + NEO_MATRIX_LEFT+
  NEO_MATRIX_ROWS + NEO_MATRIX_PROGRESSIVE,
  NEO_GRBW  + NEO_KHZ800);

const uint16_t colors[] = {
  matrix.Color(255, 0, 0), matrix.Color(0, 255, 0), matrix.Color(0, 0, 255) };

void setup() {
  matrix.setFont(&Dialog_plain_5);
  matrix.begin();
  matrix.setTextWrap(false);
  matrix.setBrightness(30);
  matrix.setTextColor(colors[0]);
}

int x    = matrix.width();
int pass = 0;

void loop() {
  matrix.fillScreen(0);
  matrix.setCursor(x, 0);
  matrix.print(F("Howdy"));
  if(--x < -36) {
    x = matrix.width();
    if(++pass >= 3) pass = 0;
    matrix.setTextColor(colors[pass]);
  }
  matrix.show();
  delay(100);
}
```

and this is the content of the font file:

```
// Created by http://oleddisplay.squix.ch/ Consider a donation
// In case of problems make sure that you are using the font file with the correct version!
const uint8_t Dialog_plain_5Bitmaps[] PROGMEM = {

    // Bitmap Data:
    0x00, // ' '
    0xF0, // '!'
    0xC0, // '"'
    0x07,0xF2, // '#'
    0x79,0xF4, // '$'
    0xD1,0x10,0xB0, // '%'
    0x88,0xCA, // '&'
    0x80, // '''
    0x2A,0x00, // '('
    0x15,0x00, // ')'
    0x08,0x00, // '*'
    0x01,0x1C,0x40, // '+'
    0x00, // ','
    0xC0, // '-'
    0x00, // '.'
    0x6A,0x00, // '/'
    0xD6,0xE0, // '0'
    0xC9,0x20, // '1'
    0x62,0x48, // '2'
    0xE8,0xE0, // '3'
    0x26,0x62, // '4'
    0x08,0x90, // '5'
    0x7A,0xE0, // '6'
    0x25,0x20, // '7'
    0xEA,0xE0, // '8'
    0xD5,0xE0, // '9'
    0x00, // ':'
    0x00, // ';'
    0x02,0xC6, // '<'
    0x77, // '='
    0x06,0x16, // '>'
    0xD0, // '?'
    0x27,0xB7,0x66,0x00, // '@'
    0x4A,0x68, // 'A'
    0xFA,0xD0, // 'B'
    0x68,0x86, // 'C'
    0xE9,0x9A, // 'D'
    0xDA,0x40, // 'E'
    0x9A,0x40, // 'F'
    0x78,0xB5, // 'G'
    0xBE,0xD0, // 'H'
    0xF0, // 'I'
    0x55,0x40, // 'J'
    0xAC,0xCA, // 'K'
    0x92,0x40, // 'L'
    0x9F,0xF9, // 'M'
    0xBF,0xD0, // 'N'
    0x69,0x96, // 'O'
    0xF7,0x40, // 'P'
    0x69,0x96,0x00, // 'Q'
    0xEA,0xCA, // 'R'
    0x91,0x60, // 'S'
    0x21,0x08,0x40, // 'T'
    0xB6,0xE0, // 'U'
    0xAA,0xA4, // 'V'
    0xAF,0xBC,0xA0, // 'W'
    0xA4,0x4A, // 'X'
    0x53,0x08,0x40, // 'Y'
    0x64,0x88, // 'Z'
    0xAA,0x80, // '['
    0xAA,0x40, // '\'
    0x55,0x40, // ']'
    0x61, // '^'
    0x70, // '_'
    0x00, // '`'
    0xDE,0x80, // 'a'
    0x9A,0xE0, // 'b'
    0x92,0x00, // 'c'
    0x3E,0xD0, // 'd'
    0xDE,0x00, // 'e'
    0x49,0x20, // 'f'
    0xF6,0xA0, // 'g'
    0x9E,0xD0, // 'h'
    0xF0, // 'i'
    0x55,0x40, // 'j'
    0x9A,0x60, // 'k'
    0xF0, // 'l'
    0xFD,0x6A, // 'm'
    0xF6,0x80, // 'n'
    0xD7,0x00, // 'o'
    0xD7,0x40, // 'p'
    0xF6,0xB0, // 'q'
    0x2A, // 'r'
    0x4C,0x80, // 's'
    0x49,0x20, // 't'
    0x16,0xD0, // 'u'
    0xB9,0x00, // 'v'
    0xD7,0x60, // 'w'
    0xCB,0x00, // 'x'
    0xB9,0x40, // 'y'
    0x68, // 'z'
    0x4A,0x24, // '{'
    0xF8, // '|'
    0x48,0xA4 // '}'
};
const GFXglyph Dialog_plain_5Glyphs[] PROGMEM = {
// bitmapOffset, width, height, xAdvance, xOffset, yOffset
      {     0,   1,   1,   3,    0,    0 }, // ' '
      {     1,   1,   4,   3,    0,   -4 }, // '!'
      {     2,   2,   2,   3,    0,   -4 }, // '"'
      {     3,   4,   4,   5,    0,   -4 }, // '#'
      {     5,   3,   5,   4,    0,   -4 }, // '$'
      {     7,   5,   4,   6,    0,   -4 }, // '%'
      {    10,   4,   4,   5,    0,   -4 }, // '&'
      {    12,   1,   2,   2,    0,   -4 }, // '''
      {    13,   2,   5,   3,    0,   -4 }, // '('
      {    15,   2,   5,   3,    0,   -4 }, // ')'
      {    17,   3,   3,   4,    0,   -4 }, // '*'
      {    19,   5,   4,   6,    0,   -4 }, // '+'
      {    22,   2,   3,   3,    0,   -2 }, // ','
      {    23,   2,   1,   3,    0,   -2 }, // '-'
      {    24,   2,   1,   3,    0,   -1 }, // '.'
      {    25,   2,   5,   3,    0,   -4 }, // '/'
      {    27,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // '0'
      {    29,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // '1'
      {    31,   4,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // '2'
      {    33,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // '3'
      {    35,   4,   4,   5,    0,   -4 }, // '4'
      {    37,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // '5'
      {    39,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // '6'
      {    41,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // '7'
      {    43,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // '8'
      {    45,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // '9'
      {    47,   2,   3,   3,    0,   -3 }, // ':'
      {    48,   2,   4,   3,    0,   -3 }, // ';'
      {    49,   4,   4,   5,    1,   -4 }, // '<'
      {    51,   4,   2,   5,    0,   -3 }, // '='
      {    52,   4,   4,   5,    0,   -4 }, // '>'
      {    54,   2,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // '?'
      {    55,   5,   5,   6,    0,   -4 }, // '@'
      {    59,   4,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'A'
      {    61,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'B'
      {    63,   4,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'C'
      {    65,   4,   4,   5,    0,   -4 }, // 'D'
      {    67,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'E'
      {    69,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'F'
      {    71,   4,   4,   5,    0,   -4 }, // 'G'
      {    73,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'H'
      {    75,   1,   4,   2,    0,   -4 }, // 'I'
      {    76,   2,   5,   2,   -1,   -4 }, // 'J'
      {    78,   4,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'K'
      {    80,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'L'
      {    82,   4,   4,   5,    0,   -4 }, // 'M'
      {    84,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'N'
      {    86,   4,   4,   5,    0,   -4 }, // 'O'
      {    88,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'P'
      {    90,   4,   5,   5,    0,   -4 }, // 'Q'
      {    93,   4,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'R'
      {    95,   3,   4,   5,    1,   -4 }, // 'S'
      {    97,   5,   4,   4,   -1,   -4 }, // 'T'
      {   100,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'U'
      {   102,   4,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'V'
      {   104,   5,   4,   6,    0,   -4 }, // 'W'
      {   107,   4,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'X'
      {   109,   5,   4,   4,   -1,   -4 }, // 'Y'
      {   112,   4,   4,   6,    1,   -4 }, // 'Z'
      {   114,   2,   5,   3,    0,   -4 }, // '['
      {   116,   2,   5,   3,    0,   -4 }, // '\'
      {   118,   2,   5,   3,    0,   -4 }, // ']'
      {   120,   4,   2,   5,    0,   -4 }, // '^'
      {   121,   4,   1,   4,   -1,    1 }, // '_'
      {   122,   2,   1,   4,    0,   -4 }, // '`'
      {   123,   3,   3,   5,    1,   -3 }, // 'a'
      {   125,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'b'
      {   127,   3,   3,   4,    0,   -3 }, // 'c'
      {   129,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'd'
      {   131,   3,   3,   5,    1,   -3 }, // 'e'
      {   133,   3,   4,   3,   -1,   -4 }, // 'f'
      {   135,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -3 }, // 'g'
      {   137,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'h'
      {   139,   1,   4,   2,    0,   -4 }, // 'i'
      {   140,   2,   5,   2,   -1,   -4 }, // 'j'
      {   142,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'k'
      {   144,   1,   4,   2,    0,   -4 }, // 'l'
      {   145,   5,   3,   6,    0,   -3 }, // 'm'
      {   147,   3,   3,   4,    0,   -3 }, // 'n'
      {   149,   3,   3,   4,    0,   -3 }, // 'o'
      {   151,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -3 }, // 'p'
      {   153,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -3 }, // 'q'
      {   155,   2,   4,   3,    0,   -4 }, // 'r'
      {   156,   3,   3,   5,    0,   -3 }, // 's'
      {   158,   3,   4,   3,   -1,   -4 }, // 't'
      {   160,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -4 }, // 'u'
      {   162,   3,   3,   4,    0,   -3 }, // 'v'
      {   164,   4,   3,   5,    0,   -3 }, // 'w'
      {   166,   3,   3,   4,    0,   -3 }, // 'x'
      {   168,   3,   4,   4,    0,   -3 }, // 'y'
      {   170,   2,   3,   5,    1,   -3 }, // 'z'
      {   171,   3,   5,   4,    0,   -4 }, // '{'
      {   173,   1,   6,   2,    0,   -4 }, // '|'
      {   174,   3,   5,   4,    0,   -4 } // '}'
};
const GFXfont Dialog_plain_5 PROGMEM = {
(uint8_t  *)Dialog_plain_5Bitmaps,(GFXglyph *)Dialog_plain_5Glyphs,0x20, 0x7E, 7};
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem until I read the library source code. Later I found the documentation reference.

The classic font cursor position is defined as the top-left corner of the character cell. For GFX and custom fonts it is the 'y' position is relative to the baseline of the character cell.

My display is 5 by 5. The TomThumb font is 3 by 5. Instead of `matrix.setCursor(x, 0);` I needed to use `matrix.setCursor(x, 5);` so the 'y' coordinate corresponds with the bottom of the pixel matrix, not the top.

It's described in [Adafruit's docs](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-gfx-graphics-library/using-fonts).